# Python - Parsing a CSV file into a new log file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with a few rows and columns separated by a ",".
I am trying to extract certain rows, add some test and print them to a new file.

```
import csv
import os

cdie_db_root_path = os.environ['CDIE_DB_ROOT']
verif_home_path = os.environ['VERIF_HOME']

with open(verif_home_path + "/gic/envir/testbench/al_gic_spi_forces.inc","w") as spi_forces:
    with open(cdie_db_root_path + "/Interrupts/verif/package_verif_signal_list.csv", "r") as fh:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader) #first line is a comment
        for row in csv_reader:
          if (int(row[1]) > 14):
            spi_forces.write(f'force {row[3]} = spi_bits[(`NUM_OF_SPI_HALF0*chip) + {row[1]}];\n')
```

I was expecting something like

```
force <PATH> = spi_bits[(`NUM_OF_SPI_HALF0*chip) + 16];
force <PATH> = spi_bits[(`NUM_OF_SPI_HALF0*chip) + 17];
force <PATH> = spi_bits[(`NUM_OF_SPI_HALF0*chip) + 18];
...
...
...
```

But instead I am getting an error:

```
  File "bin/interrupts_parsing.py", line 13
    spi_forces.write(f'force {row[3]} = spi_bits[(`NUM_OF_SPI_HALF0*chip) + {row[1]}];\n')
```

Comment: You left out the actual error message at the end of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I just needed to run with python 3.11...